# Linkedin title for engineer during foray into legal

Tags: software-industry, resume, internship, linkedin

I've been an engineer for 10+ years and my technical credentials are conveyed pretty strongly on my Linkedin profile. However, a few years ago (early mid life crisis?) I wanted a change from engineering and decided to go to law school for 3 years and did legal internships in a IP firm + law school during this period - at the end I decided I really didn't want to do it full time. I am back in engineering in a big company and have been there for 3 years, so I have managed to "shed" the legal aspect in a manner of speaking.

That said, I am wondering as I move forward in my career, how to best indicate my foray into legal in my Linkedin profile - given the "mini-break" in my strong engineering career. Alternatives being, to leave it blank during that period (don't want to do that) or indicate some side engineering start up work I did during law school that wasn't that successful (which would in scope those startups during any future tech interviews, but they didn't have meaningful progress during my full time law school + legal internships).

Thoughts/advice?

Comment: vtc such a weird question... why would having legal experience be a mark against you? asking for "advice" is off topic, this seems more a discussion question for reddit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say if your engineering background is a thoroughly documented as you are stating and you have already been back in the field for three years to just leave the legal stuff in there. I don't think many employers would fault you for having extra skills even if they do not need them. As long as you have what they are looking for I don't see how they can fault you for learning more, learning is always a good thing IMHO.

EDIT: @HLGEM's comment I didn't even think about that. I am currently working on a public website and the majority of the mandatory items and changes have come from the legal department. Examples: You can't use that image, anytime you mention that you need this disclaimer present, you can't word it like that you need to word it like this. I have no law understanding and to me some of the sentence changes don't make sense but they are positive it could open them up for legal action, So I think the law experience might be a positive like HLGEM has said.

Comment: And frankly having someone in software engineering with legal knowledge would be a real plus in any regulated environment.